# Remember last hovered Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple hoverable divs which change when being hovered... When i get off them with the mouse they return to their normal position. I would like for them to stay hovered unless another div with the same class gets hovered. So one should stay hovered. Sort of like being able to select only one div but with hovering

I tried everything that is in my knowledge

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style media="screen">
      .hoverable:hover {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .hoverable {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        transition-duration: 1s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hoverable">
      lorem
    </div>
    <div class="hoverable">
      Lorem
    </div>
    <div class="hoverable">
      Lorem
    </div>
    <div class="hoverable">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your current solution?

Comment: Perhaps you're updating state on a `mouseout` event when instead you want to update it on the next `mouseenter` event?  It's hard to be more specific without an example of what you're trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you are looking for something like this

```js
$("div.hoverable").hover(function() {
  $("div.hoverable").removeClass("hovered");
  $(this).addClass("hovered");
})
```

```css
div.hoverable {
  height: 30px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px;
}
div.hovered {
  color: red;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoverable">
  1
</div>
<div class="hoverable">
  2
</div>
<div class="hoverable">
  3
</div>
<div class="hoverable">
  4
</div>
```

Comment: Why add jQuery when you can do this without adding the extra overhead?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this.  The easiest that comes to mind is to not use the browser hover style but apply a class dynamically only on mouseenter:

```
let lastHovered = null;

const onHover = (event) => {
  if (lastHovered != null) {
    lastHovered.classList.remove('hovered');
  }
  event.target.classList.add('hovered');
  lastHovered = event.target;
}

for (const div of  document.getElementsByClassName('hoverable')) {
  div.onmouseenter = onHover;
}
```

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/minism/pen/PooRKqx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `:hover` pseudo-class. Instead, define a class and toggle it with the `mouseover` event.

```
var elArray = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverme');
elArray.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        elArray.forEach(function(el) {
            el.classList.remove('hovered');
        });
        this.classList.add('hovered');
    });
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/wvvmqGZ